# Stop the Windows Store Icon from always coming back

Tags: windows, windows-8

Is there a way to keep the Windows Store Icon from always coming back pinned to the Task Bar? It seems like every update it comes back. Very annoying.

Can I just uninstall or disable the stupid store?

Comment: Weird I unpinned mine right after 8.1 U1 came along and haven't seen it since.

Comment: But they waaaannnttt you to buy... purchase! consume! spend!